# How do you monitor Selenium Grid?

Tags: webdriver, grid

I havea grid of 18 nodes testing our application. Currently I have written a rest-api, which returnes the CPU information on the machine through a java servlet.

It's working, but it is not nice. How do you monitor grids for webdriver? Are they specific frameworks/tools for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can view all of the nodes that are connected to the running hub/server by navigating to the following address in your browser:

```
http://'hub_IP_address':'port'/grid/console#
```

It will show what machines are connected, and it will show you which of the browsers are in use for each node.

Comment: Thank you, but I was thinking more of monitoring the CPU, disk, memory etc. Something like GRAFANA.